# Convert Content-Type header into file extension

Tags: python, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

So what I am trying to do is convert a HEADER requests content-type into a file extension. The typical content-type is like this for html pages "text/html; charset=utf-8" that is the given response from python. I have looked into using the mimetype module with no success as it doesn't look like it accommodates what I am looking for.

Rundown:

I want to convert "text/html; charset=utf-8" into this ".html"

The typical image content-type is "image/jpeg" depending on the image type, but I am not too worried about images, given that most urls specify the image in the path. This is more for websites that don't end in "blahahah.html"

I do not want to use any libraries that are not in the base python library.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could split and strip:

```
r = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674905/convert-content-type-header-into-file-extension")

from mimetypes import guess_extension

print(guess_extension(r.headers['content-type'].partition(';')[0].strip()))
.htm
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a god. I couldn't for the life of me work out how that guess_extension worked.

Comment: @Shiftym no worries, `guess_extension(r.headers['content-type'])`alone  will work for certain sites but splitting should cover more bases

Comment: Weird oddity - The file extension is changing between ".htm" and ".html" on the same website

Comment: what url are you using it on?

Comment: any URL, try google.com. the file extension will differ from .html and .htm at a totally random rate

Comment: it seems to be an error in the mimetype library. Because the content-type header stays exactly the same.

Comment: @Shifty, what version of python? I ran it 100 times on google.com and always got the same. .html