# Python from url to file extension

Tags: python, urllib, content-type

I have uploaded a lot of playlist files [here](https://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/)

The code i wrote is:

```
path = 'playlist_files/samples'
files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:
    filename = "http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/"+name
    r = requests.get(filename, verify=False, timeout=5)
    print(filename+" "+r.headers['content-type'])
```

The output is:

```
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.pls application/pls+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test05.m3u audio/x-mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test05.wpl application/vnd.ms-wpl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.pla text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.ram audio/x-pn-realaudio
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.hypetape text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.rss application/rss+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.asx video/x-ms-asf
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.mpcpl text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.xspf application/x-xspf+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.rmp text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.kpl text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.wpl application/vnd.ms-wpl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.wax audio/x-ms-wax
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.pls application/pls+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.asx video/x-ms-asf
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.wpl application/vnd.ms-wpl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test06.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test06.asx video/x-ms-asf
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.m3u audio/x-mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.b4s text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.rmp text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.wpl application/vnd.ms-wpl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test06.m3u audio/x-mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.m3u audio/x-mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.atom application/atom+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.rss application/rss+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.rmp text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.pls application/pls+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.plist text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.mpcpl text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.plp text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test05.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.plp text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test06.rss application/rss+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.asx video/x-ms-asf
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.ram audio/x-pn-realaudio
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.rss application/rss+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.atom application/atom+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.rmp text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test05.pls application/pls+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.wvx video/x-ms-wvx
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.m3u audio/x-mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.xml text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.mpcpl text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.wpl application/vnd.ms-wpl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.mpcpl text/plain
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test01.m3u8 application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.rss application/rss+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.pls application/pls+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test07.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test04.asx video/x-ms-asf
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.xspf application/x-xspf+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test05.rss application/rss+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.m3u audio/x-mpegurl
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test03.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test05.asx video/x-ms-asf
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.plist text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test08.smil application/smil+xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test02.b4s text/xml
http://users.sch.gr/apappas/temp/test07.asx video/x-ms-asf
```

Now i want from content-type or from the downloaded file to extract the extension.

For example: http://www.example.com/index.php?file=22 ---> content-type: some_content_type -> file_extension = ?

Is that possible?

Edit: `filename.split(".")[-1]` is not a valid answer because for http://www.example.com/index.php?file=22 the extension would be php?file=22 false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Content-Type header into file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674905/convert-content-type-header-into-file-extension)

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicoo a little. it don't catch all the cases.

Comment: I want just to save from the server, and i am searching the extension for all the cases.

Comment: Which cases doesn't it work for? Did you try it?

Comment: Yes wait i will paste the output in jsfiddle.

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco https://jsfiddle.net/y3kLo6ag/

Comment: I see. It seems it doesn't work for some very uncommon file extensions. You could check the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) to see if there are some other options. You might even have to add custom mappings for some of the extensions. I've also noticed that you won't be able to guess the extension of some of them just by looking at their content-type. For example, `test02.mpcpl text/plain`, which says that `test02` is a plain text file, when actually it has some other extension. The script has no way of knowing that

Comment: requests.get(filename, stream=True) stream=True changes something in that situation?

Comment: I've posted an answer with a simple way to get the extensions from the URLs

Comment: Might the file name be included in the other header values? As an aside, I would recommend using pathlib instead of the os module.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the file name like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

url = "http://www.example.com/index.php.gz?file=22"
clean_path = urlparse(url).path
extension = os.path.splitext(clean_path)[1]
```

Comment: check my anwer. Feel free to comment.

Comment: Why don't you use both solutions? You could try to get an extension through `mimetypes`, and if it returns `None`, then you can try to get it from the file's extension with the code above

Comment: You can't accept two different answers, so just accept the one that helped you the most!

Answer (score 0):

```
import mimetypes

extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(type, strict=True)

if(extension=="None"):
    try:
         parse_pls_file(filename)
         parse_m3u_file(filename)
         ....
         parse_asx_file(filename)
    except Exception as e:
         print(e)
else:
#save file as `filename+extension`
```

I have wrote a lot of this parsers, and i will write the rest in some days.
So, i think that's ok. Am i right?

Comment: Are you sure you want to manually parse the file for each of the possible extensions? I don't think it's a good idea. Your code might grow very large, and you would have to modify it each time you receive a file with an extension you hadn't seen before.